# Remove parts of a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Im using the FolderBrowserDialog to pick a path.

It will return for ex. this= C:\Mypath1\Mypath2\DOCS
I would like to remove everything but DOCS.

If i use VBA i would use a InStrRev combined with a left. But now in in VB.net and im not sure how to achieve this, im pretty sure there is something better than my old VBA way?

Anyone there that could help, google failed me.

Comment: For directory information, use the Path class to extract that.  You do have to improve your google skills.

Comment: Since you mentioned InStrRev: strYourString.Substring(strYourString.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\Mypath1\Mypath2\DOCS")
```

Which returns DOCS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do. But maybe this can help you get the last part of a string

```
Dim fullPath As String = " C:\Mypath1\Mypath2\DOCS"
Dim Parts As String() = fullPath.Split("\")
Dim lastPart As String = Parts(Parts.Length - 1)
```